# How to monitor the time span between the request and response using prometheus java client

Tags: java, prometheus

I am writing a Restful web api. I am using prometheus for monitoring my api . for example this is how i am keeping a count of total request and failed requests.

```
static final Counter requests = Counter.build()
         .name("requests_total").help("Total requests.").register();
static final Counter failedRequests = Counter.build()
         .name("requests_failed_total").help("Total failed requests.").register();
```

then i increment the counters like below

```
requests.inc();
failedRequests.inc();
```

the same way i would like to monitor the time span between the request and response of api call. Is there a prometheus java client which would help me doing this.?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Summary's timing functinoality will let you do this: https://github.com/prometheus/client_java#summary